# How to run a demo in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to run [this](https://github.com/domwoolf/somic1) demo. But when I run the command it says

> Error in demo(SOMIC) : No demo found for the topic 'SOMIC'.

Is it the problem of the path or something completely different? I have set the working directory to the folder.

Thank you

Comment: Did you installed and called the package like `library(somic1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install the package with `devtools::install_github('domwoolf/somic1')`.

Then load the package into your environment with `library(SOMic)`.
The demo should then be available with `demo(SOMIC)`.